# MVC 4 Bundling causes missing image in Kendo UI

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have created a new MVC 4 application and am trying to migrate an existing MVC 3 application over. Everything works fine until I try to use the new Bundling feature and when I bundle Kendo css files the arrow on dropdowns and numeric textboxes disappear. They function ok, just missing the images. The files seem to bundle just fine. I have researched extensively and have tried renaming the files to remove the "min" and still have the same issue.

Here are the files I am trying to bundle:

```
 <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/kendo.common.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/kendo.default.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/kendo.blueopal.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

When I bundle them like so the issues appear :

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/cssBundle").Include(
             "~/Content/kendo/kendo.common.min.css",
             "~/Content/kendo/kendo.default.min.css",
             "~/Content/kendo/kendo.blueopal.min.css"
             ));
```

Comment: You still have the minified files. ASP.NET MVC bundling ignores files with  ending with .min.css or .min.js

Comment: @Ufuk Hacıoğulları, Thanks. I renamed the files to not include the min part as I had read you could do but got the same behavior.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem.
CssRewriteUrlTransform should do the trick:

```
.Include("~/Content/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.common.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
```

Comment: this one really should be the answer. We recently tried it and it works.

Answer (score 1):

First off, there is no need to minify files that have already been minified. The `StyleBundle` class will try to minify the Kendo .min files again, which is unnecessary. Use the `Bundle` class instead.

Secondly, the `.Include()` method takes a second parameter of `params IItemTransform[] transforms`. You can pass `new CssRewriteUrlTransform()` as that parameter, so your CSS will have the right paths.

Example:

```
bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/Content/cssBundle")
    .Include("~/Content/kendo/kendo.common.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()),
    .Include("~/Content/kendo/kendo.default.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()),
    .Include("~/Content/kendo/kendo.blueopal.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a pain, but I usually just modify the .css files and do a find/replace to get the correct paths.

Otherwise, you can set the bundle to be the same directory that Kendo is in, like this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendo").Include(
             "~/Content/kendo/kendo.common.min.css",
             "~/Content/kendo/kendo.default.min.css",
             "~/Content/kendo/kendo.blueopal.min.css"
             ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct this problem by configuring routes in my application for the problem locations.

```
// Route for bundles problem.
routes.MapRoute("ResourcesFix", "bundles/{folder}/{path}", 
    new { controller = "Redirect", action = "Index" });

// Redirect for requests.
public class RedirectController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(String folder, String path)
    {
        return Redirect("~/Content/kendo/" + 
          WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KendoVersion"] + "/" + folder + "/" + path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following class extension,

```
 public static class BundleConfigExt
    {
        public static Bundle CustomCssInclude(this Bundle bundle, params string[] virtualPaths)
        {
            foreach (var virtualPath in virtualPaths)
            {
                if (virtualPath.IndexOf("~/Content/kendo/") > -1) //OR
                //// if (virtualPath.IndexOf("~/Content/kendo/") > -1 || virtualPath.IndexOf("~/Content/ExternalCss/") > -1)
                {
                    bundle.Include(virtualPath, new CssRewriteUrlTransform());
                }
                else
                {
                    bundle.Include(virtualPath);
                }
            }

            return bundle;
        }
    }
```

**Call .CustomCssInclude() extension method instead of .Include(),**

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Bundles/AllArabicCss").CustomCssInclude(
                "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                "~/Content/kendo/kendo.common.*",
                "~/Content/kendo/kendo.default.min.css",
                //...
                "~/Content/kendo/kendo.bootstrap.min.css",
                "~/Content/ExternalCss/custom.css",
                "~/Content/ExternalCss/tab-responsive.css",
                "~/Content/ExternalCss/mobile-responsive.css"));
```